# Autodiscovery and mapping to controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java

I was going through this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql in order to configure graphql and map objects directly to POJO, however with the new packages from https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring the interfaces used in the tutorial don't seem to be there anymore.

Is it possible to use the same techniques (maybe using an additional package) to map grapqhl request to objects and configure datafetchers in an easier fashion than manually ?

Note that I would like this to be webflux compatible not webmvc.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Starter that Baeldung tutorial is using is coming from [graphql-java-kickstart](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot), and it is *not* the same as [the official graphql-java Spring Starter](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring).

Their programming models are different. The Kickstart one relies on `graphql-java-tools`, while the other one uses `graphql-java` directly. So you can just keep using the latest version of the Kickstart Spring Starter. Not sure whether it works with WebFlux, but I'd expect so.

There's also my project, [GraphQL SPQR Spring Starter](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter) and a sample app [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter-sample). The latest version (0.0.4) works with WebFlux, but for queries and mutations only, subscription support is coming.